# After .eq() how to continue looking for selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

After using .eq() I'm not sure how to proceed with my CSS selector to look for "Happy World" and eventually tap on it.

Using the Chrome dev tool console, I typed:

```
$('.search-cell').eq('0')
```

and the selector works and returns the following HTML on the console:

```
<div class="search-cell">

  <div class="media-img">
    <img src="image.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="media-body">
    <h1 class="title">Happy World
        <span class="badge">1st</span>      
    </h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle">Balloon flyer</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

I tried:

```
$('.search-cell').eq('0').children('.media-body')
```

and it returned [].

My mind is wrapped with XPATH concepts, so I was thinking eventually it would look like this:

```
$('.search-cell').eq('0').(Not sure what to put?????).trigger('tap)
```

What am I missing after .eq()?

Comment: Try with `.find(".media-body")`

Comment: How can `.search-cell.searchtable` match that element when it only has the class `.search-cell`?

Comment: Whats gives `console.log($('.search-cell.searchtable').eq(0)[0]);` ?

Comment: Sorry let me edit my question, but find() seems to be working..

Comment: Why not `$('.search-cell:first .media-body').trigger('tap')`?

Comment: I think I got it with $('.search-cell .media-body').find('.title').trigger('tap') ..A combination of you guys helped thank you!

Comment: And thank you @kunalbhat meager tymeJV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery's `find` to get the descendants of your element filtered by the 'media-body' selector.

```
$('.search-cell').eq('0').find('.media-body');
```

I've created a [Codepen example](http://cdpn.io/pCdyu) that prints to console the text of the element.

**For example**

```
console.log($('.search-cell').eq('0').find('.media-body').text());
```

*Potentially anachronistic note:*
Additionally, as @BoltClock pointed out in the comments, you are attempting to match against an additional selector `'.searchtable'`, which doesn't exist in your sample code. I've edited that for my example.